# How to update a single column of a selected row in gridview using a button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a Select button at the end of each row in gridview. I also have a separate button that I want to use to update one of the column of the selected row. This column contains a checkbox, I want to put a check in it when I click the button.

I do not want to use an Update button inside the gridview because I do not want the user to be able to change any other column.

Can anyone help? I have been researching this for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot of option regarding your problem..
You could use Gridview's RowCreated or RowDataBound events or even on the buttons onclick event if that button is on the same row of the gridview(just get the sender etc//based on your logic).

here are some code snippet

```
If

e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(sender,   
"Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex.ToString))

End If
```

Comment: The update button is completely separated from the gridview. Is it possible to do it this way or do I have to include it in the gridview absolutely?

Comment: I think it will be better if you include it inside your gridview

Comment: I cannot do this, I will have to find another way.